# Mutable borrow not released after function call ends

Tags: rust

In the below code, I want to move the code in 'case1' to a function call. But I am unable to call the new function more than once as it complains about taking mutable borrow twice.

I assumed that mutable borrow will end after the first call but it doesn't. It gives the error "error[E0499]: cannot borrow `c` as mutable more than once at a time".

Help me figure out why the borrow doesn't end when fn ends and also how can I accomplish the behavior of case 1 through a fn call.
Of course below program is made up to recreate an example of the error I encountered in another bigger function.

Thanks

```
pub struct A {}
pub struct B<T> {
    pub a: T,
}
pub struct C<'a, T> {
    pub b: &'a B<T>,
}
fn main() {
    println!("Hello world!!!");
    let b = B {
        a:A{},
    };
    let b2 = B {
        a:A{},
    };
    let mut c = C{
        b: &b,
    };
//#ifdef case1
    c.b = &b;
    c.b = &b2;
//#else
    mc(&b, &mut c);
    mc(&b2, &mut c);
//#endif
}
fn mc<'a>(b: &'a B<A>, c: &'a mut C<'a, A>) {
    c.b = b;
}
```

Edit: While this is flagged as duplicate, the linked question doesn't explain how to change code in case 1 into a fn call. But thankfully Jmb has anwered it in comment, which I will copy here in case googlers stumble here.

```
fn mc<'a, 'b: 'a>(b: &'a B<A>, c: &'a mut C<'b, A>)
```

or even better:

```
fn mc<'a>(b: &'a B<A>, c: &mut C<'a, A>)
```

as only lifetime of b and c.b need explicit specification in this case, not the lifetime of c itself.

Comment: `&'a mut C<'a>` is _always_ wrong, add a second lifetime so that you can take `&'a mut C<'b, A>`

Comment: fn mc<'a, 'b>(b: &'a B<A>, c: &'a mut C<'b, A>) fails with error: lifetime may not live long enough.
Also can you please explain a bit about what &'a mut C<'a> represents so that it's always wrong.

Comment: You need to tell the compiler that `'b` lives longer than `'a`: `fn mc<'a, 'b: 'a>(b: &'a B<A>, c: &'a mut C<'b, A>)`. For an explanation, look at the linked duplicate.

Comment: c.b = b;
assignment requires that `'a` must outlive `'b`

Comment: Well then you just need `b: &'b B<A>`

Comment: That's... wow. Thanks a lot.